# Remix offline/online freezes and goes blank when TX of a test contract being debugged with a test function having an unammed calldata array parameter

Tags: remix

A test contract deployed:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.11;
import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract Workdesk {
function calldataCheck(uint256[] calldata) external {
        // assembly {
        //     // mstore(0x00, calldataload(0x00))
        //     // mstore(0x20, calldataload(0x04))
        //     // mstore(0x00, calldataload(list))
        //     // mstore(0x20, calldataload(list2.offset))
        // }
    }
}
```

Then when debugged, IDE  freezes and everything goes blank